# Proof of Gronwall's Inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about the proof of Gronwall's inequality as given in *Chicone: Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications*.

**Gronwall:** Suppose that $a<b$ and let $\alpha, \phi,$ and $\psi$ be nonnegative continuous functions defined on the interval $[a,b]$. Moreover, suppose that $\alpha$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ with nonnegative continuous derivative $\dot\alpha$. If, for all $t \in [a,b]$, $$\phi(t) \leq \alpha(t) + \int_{a}^{t}\psi(s)\phi(s)ds,$$ then $$\phi(t) \leq \alpha(t)e^{\int_{a}^{t}\phi(s)ds}$$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.

**Proof:** Assume for the moment that $\alpha(a)>0$. In this case $\alpha(t) \geq \alpha(a)>0$ on the interval $[a,b]$. The function on the interval $[a,b]$ defined by $t \mapsto \alpha(t) + \int_{a}^{t}\psi(s)\phi(s)ds$ is positive and exceeds $\phi$.

**The last sentence doesn't make sense.** I understand the function is positive. But how does it exceed $\phi$?

Comment: uhm -- this is the assumption.

Comment: Right, but the proof statement makes it sound like it is verifiable.

Comment: It just repeats the assumption made in the theorem. If a theorem states an assumption as a prerequisite, it is of course something which you can use to prove it.